# Font not sizing in Date Picker

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am using 3.1.3.GA sdk, Alloys and 2.3.4 Android Emulator. I have created a Date picker and its size is too small so as specified I used fontSize attribute to increase its column value text size but not worked as expected. My code, 
**index.js**

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    layout: 'vertical',
    modal: true
});  
var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
    type:Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,
    minDate:new Date(2009,0,1),
    maxDate:new Date(2014,11,31),
    value:new Date(2014,3,12),
    top:50,
    width: 300,
    height: 500,
    font: {fontSize: 40},
    useSpinner: true
});

win.add(picker);
win.open();
```

Am getting a UI like [this](http://postimg.org/image/65a1j3wwd/). I need to increase the fontSize of the picker column, is it possible or its a bug?. In [jira tickets](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-14007?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) its mentioned as solved. Any suggestions?.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has not been implemented yet. The [ticket you refer](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-14007?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) to has a status of "Open."

Also this property is not mentioned anywhere in the Picker docs except for [PickerRow](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.PickerRow-property-font), unfortunately only for MobileWeb and Tizen.

If you really need this, it would not be too difficult to write your own custom picker by extending the [TiUiNativePicker class](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/android/modules/ui/src/java/ti/modules/titanium/ui/widget/picker/TiUINativePicker.java).

Comment: Ok Thank you. I will have a look at it Josiah.

Answer (score 0):

I solved these problems in Ti v3.3.0/v3.4.0 by defining the fontsize for Android in the picker creation (as above), and for iPhone in the row creation:

```
        var row = Ti.UI.createPickerRow({
            fontSize : someFontSize, 
            title : someTitle
        });
        column1.addRow(row);
```

Do it both ways unconditionally, and you're covered.